# Get usb device uri path cups printer

Tags: ubuntu, printing, cups

I need to create a script that adds a printer on the fly. We have several Brother printers, and each of them has a different serial number. The device uri for a printer is in the following format: `usb://Brother/QL-700?serial=XXXXXXXXX`.

I need to get this device uri, including the serial number programmatically to use with `lpadmin` option `-v`.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

```
 [lpstat - t]
```

will give you [usb://] device details

```
[lsusb -v | grep -E '\<(Bus|iProduct|bDeviceClass|bDeviceProtocol|iSerial)' 2>/dev/null]
```

will give you serial number.